# Get the last inserted data in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get recent data that has been inserted into the database?

I'm using the following code to insert:

```
DB.One one = new DB.One();
one.Name = "Name";

db.One.InsertOnSubmit(one);
db.SubmitChanges();

DB.Two two = new DB.Two();
two.OID = one.ID;
two.Age = 20;

db.Two.InsertOnSubmit(two);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

When I query about the data I use:

```
var data = from d in db.One
           where d.Name.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim())
           select d;

dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

dataGridView2.DataSource = data;
dataGridView2.DataMember = "Two";
```

In datagridview2 it does not display the data, but when I restart the program.
One and Two tables contain a relationship between One.ID -> Two.OID

Comment: Try appending `ToList()` to your query `data`

Comment: I don't see you inserting data. Further, how can you set a DataMember when data is a single list? What do you intend to do there?

Comment: One and Two tables contain a relationship between One.ID -> Two.OID

Answer (score 1):

you have query, but for the binding you need to have the data, try below

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = data.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

just add [`.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var data = (from d in db.One
           where d.Name.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim())
           select d).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = from d in db.One
           where d.Name.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim())
           select d;
```

This statement, will not be executed until you call something like `.Count()` or `.ToList()`, this is known as [`Deferred Execution`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). Take a [`look at the table in this article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx), and you'll see the classifications of the operators.

To get the latest, may want to look at using the [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx).

```
var data = from d in db.One.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateAdded);//for example
```

**EDIT**: Based on your update

Do you want `dataGridView2` to use `db.Two`?

```
var data = (from d in db.One
           where d.Name.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim())
           select d).ToList();

var data2 = (from d in db.Two
           where d.Name.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim())
           select d).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
dataGridView2.DataSource = data2;
```

Comment: relationship in One and Two tables
when row selected changed in datagridview1 the data in datagridview2 display only relationship data. not all data from Two table

Comment: There needs to be far more information in the question, it's difficult to answer a question with very little detail.

Answer (score 0):

Call `dataGridView.DataBind();` method after assigning the data.